# In the Inline "open and write file" is the close() implicit?

Tags: python, file

In Python (>2.7) does the code :

```
open('tick.001', 'w').write('test')
```

has the same result as :

```
ftest  = open('tick.001', 'w')
ftest.write('test')
ftest.close()
```

and where to find documentation about the 'close' for this inline functionnality ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `close()` here happens when the `file` object is deallocated from memory, as part of its deletion logic. Because modern Pythons on other virtual machines — like Java and .NET — cannot control when an object is deallocated from memory, it is no longer considered good Python to `open()` like this without a `close()`. The recommendation today is to use a `with` statement, which explicitly requests a `close()` when the block is exited:

```
with open('myfile') as f:
    # use the file
# when you get back out to this level of code, the file is closed
```

If you do not need a name `f` for the file, then you can omit the `as` clause from the statement:

```
with open('myfile'):
    # use the file
# when you get back out to this level of code, the file is closed
```

Comment: is it possible to do it inline or without a temporary `f`?

Comment: Yes, I have supplemented the question to show how to not create a name `f` for the file.

Comment: @kirill_igum, maybe i'm not creative enough, but what sort of application would you open a file without needing a handle to read/write from it?

Comment: @Chris — I can imagine a script wanting to create, say, a `.git/index.lock` file to signal other applications to stay out of the way. It could open with mode `'x'` to force failure if the file already existed.

Comment: @Chris smtn like `open('file').print()`. i know it's not possible in python and the syntax doesn't allow it but that's what i had in mind at that time -- one-line.

Comment: Mostly a good answer (which is why I upvoted it) but it still doesn't answer the whole question. Where is this documented?

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch — I'm not aware of any documentation. The stdlib docs only describe the `with` statement or explicit `close`, without any mention of implicit closing when the object is deallocated. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files