# Python linecount in a file

Tags: python

For the following:

```
def linecount(filename):
    count = 0
    for x in open(filename):
        count += 1
    return count
```

How does the script 'know' that each line is a separate element?
For 'file' type, is this how it is essentially separated -- by line? Thank you

Comment: You should really close the file when you're done with it.`</nitpick>`

Comment: Or use the `with` statement (Python 2.6+)!

Comment: @Matt Ball Python automatically closes file handles when they go out of scope.

Comment: @Swiss CPython does. Python itself doesn't make any guarantees, and this works differently in implementations without a refcounting GC (i.e. all the other ones, including PyPy and Jython).

Comment: @Swiss: as I said, it's a nitpick - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362901/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you iterate over a `file` object, it acts as if you are iterating over:

```
open(filename).readlines()
```

but without storing to memory (which is good for huge files).

---

The Python documentation explains this in more detail, but here's the juicy stuff:

```
>>> f = open('foo.txt', 'r')
>>> f.readlines()
['This is the first line of the file.\n', 'Second line of the file\n']
```

An alternative approach to reading lines is to loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simpler code:

```
>>> for line in f:
        print line,

This is the first line of the file.
Second line of the file
```

Comment: Right, and that's because a file object is its own iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The file class reads in data from the file, and yields a new line whenever it encounters a linebreak. (You can find the actual implementation of this in [iobase.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9bc342724319/Modules/_io/iobase.c) starting around line 551)

Comment: The question is not that. The question is *how* does it know of a new line.

Comment: @A By buffering and yielding when it finds a newline character. Which is what I said. Does it need to do anything else to discover that there's a new line?

Answer (score 0):

I've been disappointed with the speed of the Python approach. I've resorted to calling wc.exe through os.popen to get the fastest possible result:

```
int(os.popen("wc -l " + filename).read().strip().split()[0])
```